# Problems with CSS sticky footer

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to implement a CSS sticky footer.

The issue is there is a content DIV that is extending beyond its container causing scroll bars that are not desirable and the background-image hung off the page div does not extend the full height of the document.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="page">
          <div id="header">
            <dl>
                <dt>Header links -</dt>
                <dd><a href="#">link 1</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#">link 2</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#">link 3</a></dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p><a id="modal" href="popup.html" target="_blank">link to popup</a></p>
        </div>      
        <div id="footer">
            <dl>
                <dt>Footer links -</dt>
                <dd><a href="#">link 1</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#">link 2</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#">link 3</a></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------- global */

html, 
body {
    color:#969696;
    font-size:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    font:normal 200 70% Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;  
}

a, 
a:link, 
a:visited, 
a:hover, 
a:active {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ff8400;
    color:#ff8400;
    text-decoration:none;}

a:hover {
    border-bottom-style:solid;}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------- layout */

#page {
    background:url("../images/bgMain.jpg") repeat-y center top;     
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:1024px;
}

dl, 
dt, 
dd {
    float:left;
} 


dd {
    margin:0 .2em 0;
}

dd:after {
    color:#969696;
    content:"|";
    padding:0 0 0 .3em;
}

dd:last-child:after {
    content:"";
}

/*----------------- header */

#header {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:726px;
}

#header dl {
    float:right;
    line-height:60px;
}

/*----------------- content body */

#content {
    background:#fff;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);    
        -moz-box-shadow:0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    clear:both;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;  
    min-height:100%;
    padding:16px 13px 22px;
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
}

/*----------------- footer */

#footer {
    clear:both;
    margin:-22px auto;
    position:relative;
    width:726px;
}

#footer dl {
    display:inline; 
    margin:0 0 0 13px;
}

#footer a, 
#footer a:link, 
#footer a:visited, 
#footer a:hover, 
#footer a:active {
    border-bottom-color:#969696;
    color:#969696;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fantastic [**CSS Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/) website has, in their [Snippets](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/) area a snippet for a Sticky Footer

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

or using jQuery

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

*latest link with demo*

Comment: Also see [Sticky Footer, Five Ways](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 8):

Modern Clean CSS “Sticky Footer” from [James Dean](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you need to change your rules for the #footer to include a defined height, and then a negative margin-top rule with a value equal to your defined height.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a very clean CSS footer a couple days ago, you could find it useful.

http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer

Answer (score 3):

You will find on this github repository ([Bredele css sticky footer](https://github.com/bredele/css-bundle/tree/master/sticky-footer)) two versions of sticky footers : one with a header and an other one without.

Both these versions use display:table (works with IE8) with no extra markups, no clearfix and a flexible content height. 
Moreover, the header height doesn't depend on the content padding or a relative viewport!

Hope it'll be helpful!

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the scrollbars by using

```
overflow: hidden
```

on the container where they appear.

Comment: Sorry i should clarify that the scrollbars are on the browser caused by the content div extending the page.  No scrollbars are present on the actual elements.

Comment: html, body { overflow: hidden; }

Comment: Makes the footer dissapear :(

Comment: Well, why don't you position your footer absolutely with bottom: 0px?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following style for the footer:

```
#footer{position:absolute;bottom:0}
```

This will put it at the bottom of the screen at all times, if you want it at the bottom of `<div id="page">` add

```
#page{position:relative}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about when you don't know the height of the footer, such as with a responsive layout? Is the only option to use JavaScript and window.onresize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this style:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 8rem 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.myFooter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 8rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very helpful CSS trick that will always stick your footer to the bottom, even if the content height is lower than the height of the viewport.

See HTML code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Sticky Footer</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
  <footer>&copy; 2016</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

See CSS code below:

```
body {
 margin: 0; /* If not already reset */
}

.content {
 min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

footer {
 height: 20px;
}
```

In your case I would wrap the nav and article in a "content" div. And give it a min-height value of calc(100vh - 100px).

Here is the article source: [Sticky CSS Footer](https://priteshgupta.com/2016/05/sticky-css-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

Use FlexBox

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

with this I resolved all the problem with the footer with a not full content page.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as all in this world!, you only need to stick to the bottom...

Use this next code:

```js
//This is jus't a stupid detail
//So, don't take much importance!

const text = document.getElementById('footer');

text.onmouseover = function(){
  text.style.color = "red";
}

text.onmouseleave = function(){
  text.style.color = "white";
}

while (e = true){
  text.innerText = "Hello!";
  setTimeout(function(){
   text.innerText = "I love coding";
   setTimeout(function(){
    text.innerText = "Codede by INovomiast";
   }, 1500);
  },1500);
}
```

```css
footer{
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>PAGE CONTENT</h1>
    <footer>
      <center>
        <h1 id='footer'>FOOTER!</h1>
      </center>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```