# How to create a footer which stick to the bottom of the screen

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

Hi,

How can I get create a footer stick to the bottom of a screen (not page) despite there is scroll bar on the side?
For example like this:
http://www.sportingnews.com/

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS sticky footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer), plus [so many other sticky footer questions...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+sticky+footer).

Comment: let me google that for you....

Answer (score 1):

[Fixed footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/) (Compatible with IE6)

You can see a demo [here](http://www.flashjunior.ch/school/footers/fixed.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

Its called **stickyfooter**

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, and each has its own advantages/disadvantages (especially browser-compatibility.)  Probably the easiest is fixed positioning, which doesnt work in IE6.

```
.bar {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;  /* May need to be tweaked, depending on your design and functionality. */
}
```

If you need IE6 compatibility, you can implement a JS file which enables it (and more) for IE6. Check out [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: fixed;bottom: 0px;">Footer text</div>
```