# Format a DIV into a top-most panel bar

Tags: css, html

I'm writing some CSS. I want to create a panel bar, which is always top-most and stays at the bottom of the page, `height` is fixed at 50px and `width` is unknown. Can a normal DIV do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS sticky footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the WINDOW? Or the bottom of a page?

If you're looking for it to be at the bottom of your document, then you're looking for something like [Sticky-Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

If you want it at the bottom of the window and to remain while you scroll, you need [Position:fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Edit: If you want it to stay on the bottom of the window like the Facebook chat bar, you need this:

```
.bottom{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: it looks like the Facebook chat bar

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed; bottom:0` should do the trick.

Comment: There are numerous complications that make it not so simple. The biggest one is that the bottom of the document may not always be the height of the browser window. You need some tricks to keep the div at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` are block elements, so inheritly are full width of their containing element. If their containing element is the `body` tag, and has no width restrictions set, the div should be full browser width.

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000; /* optional, but I set for insurance */
}
```