# Forcing footer to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

I am hard at work developing a webservice but i have run into a problem getting the websites footer to stay at the bottom of the page and its starting to become fustrating as i have tried every single "sticky footer" script their is and none seem to work.

```
#footer {
background:#212121 url(../images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Kind Regards,
**Nathaniel Blackburn**

Comment: It seems like he's asking how to make a footer div on the bottom of a web page.  The code is implicit.

Comment: +1 for "kind regards". It's great to some extra friendliness around here

Comment: @nblackburn, did any of these options work for you?

Answer (score 6):

I devised this simple solution (tested it in Firefox and Chrome). First define this function in a javascript file:

```
function footer() {
    if ($(window).height() > $('body').height())
        {
        var extra = $(window).height() - $('body').height();
        $('footer').css('margin-top', extra);
        }
    }
```

And then simply call it when the document is ready, with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't my favorite way to make footers but I think you're looking for position: fixed.

```
 #footer {
      background: #212121 url(../images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%; }
```

What you're running into with all of the other approaches is that pages like About Us have a `<body>` that is not as tall as the browser window so the footer is at the bottom of the page but not the window.  You could either make some changes to make the body element taller or just go with with `fixed`, which means the footer should position itself relative to the browser window.

Comment: This does sound exactly like what he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this CSS?

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: This would need a relative position set container on the body element, and no hierarchy changing the positioning in between.  Doable, but it also depends on the page being at least as long as the window, as I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS?

```
#footer{ position: fixed; left: 1em; right: 1em; bottom: 0em; text-align: center; }
```

put a

```
<div id="footer">footer stuff</div>
```

on the page with that css, and the footer will stick just fine.

(Despite suggestions to the contrary, this will not "mess up" a page.  It will force the div to the bottom of the window, regardless of the size of the page.  If there is some distinction to be made between *floating* and *sticking*, I can provide more context in how this sort of thing can be done.)

Comment: That would mess up his page. All he has to do is change position of the footer to absolute. Then, set the width to 100%. It worked; I tried it.

Comment: Sorry, I want it to stick to the bottom, not float at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you're qualifying the difference?  What functionality are you missing?  @nmagerko, how do you expect that would mess up his page?  I use this all the time, and it has never done so.

Comment: Your page is not his page. I'm sure you understand the concept that with each differing class, a working technique changes drastically.

Comment: @nmagerko, Look, I'm not trying to be difficult here, but what are you going on about?  How could a fixed position div ever mess up a page? it sticks to the bottom of the window, nothing else interferes.  The only time that doesn't happen is if the browser doesn't support CSS 2.1.  I would like an explanation of how this would "mess up" someone's page.  Give me an example and I'll shut up about it.

Comment: I think this is an extended discussion. That is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have given this solution to someone else in a very similar problem:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:1200px; //???
    max-height:1200px; //???
    position:relative;
    ....
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    ....
}
```