# My <footer> keeps jumping to the top of the page

Tags: css, html, footer

Hello I am writing a site using `Aptana Studio 3` I at this stage have 1 `<div>` for content one `<nav>` for site navigation and one `<footer>` containing a simple copyright.
 I am currently experimenting with

```
float:left;
float:right;
```

This has caused my `<footer>` to jump to the very top of the page and it won't leave, please help me find a solution which doesn't involve `position:absolute;` or failing that a way for the absolute position to be centred.

Comment: are you developing in IE8- ? they don't support those tags natively

Comment: Post the smallest HTML code that can show the problem.

Comment: Create a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net) of your html please

Comment: Have you tried using display:block; ?   http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @Ibu http://jsfiddle.net/QAe3a/

Comment: @Samjus Thank you but it didn't help.

Comment: No Problem :). Figured it may be worth a shot. I'm new to all of this jazz haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your `<nav>` and content `<div>` in a wrapper and add a CSS rule to wrapper `overflow: hidden` - http://jsfiddle.net/7kpuH/

UPDATE: for the footer that sticks to the very bottom of the page you might want to loo here - [Problems with CSS sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

```
<section>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>

    <nav>
        navigation
    </nav>    
</section>

<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

CSS

```
section, footer { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background: #eee; }
section { overflow: hidden }

#content { background: orange; width: 250px; float: left; padding: 20px; }
nav { background: beige; width: 150px; float: right; padding: 20px; }

footer { padding: 20px 0; border-top: 5px solid #fff }
```

Comment: Doesnt he want the footer to be underneath the content? Your example in jsFiddle is pushing it to the right of it

Comment: @Samjus I've checked in Safari, Chrome and FF both on Mac and PC - the footer stays underneath the `section`

Comment: You win haha. I totally forgot I was using IE 8 because work doesn't allow other browsers.  Good job :)

Comment: This works the footer is below the wrapper, I just used the `overflow: hidden;` part but is there a solution for it to be at the very bottom of the page and not just bellow the wrapper?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to the sticky footer thread

Comment: Sorry but the CSS which was linked in that question, didn't help at all when I applied it to my `<div>` #wrapper alongside overflow hidden the footer still appeared right at the bottom of the wrapper. And when I tried without the overflow the footer disappeared covered up I believe by the wrapper.

Comment: you don't just copypaste and expect it to work, you have to change the elements, id-s, classes accordingly and then -  http://jsfiddle.net/8g87D/

Comment: Thank you this, I'll experiment more with this and I have modified it I mostly use classes where you use id's etc it's just that in those links I said there were other solutions than your last one which left out the negative margin top on the <footer>.