# Css align to bottom of page

Tags: css

I want my footer to always be on the bottom and move to adjust to the size of the content inside the page. Right now I have dynamic content that covers the footer because it's to much content.

How can I fix my CSS:

```css
div#Footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: Black;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS sticky footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 13):

Its a little unclear what you want but this code has worked well for me.

Credit - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/

```
#footer {   
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a simpler solution.

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Smaller content wouldn't stretch the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more html/css to be positive of what is going on here, but it sounds like your footer is being covered by your content page. If this is the case then setting a z-index on the footer will probably sort the issue.

```
z-index: 1000;
```

This can also typically be sorted by making sure your footer appears at the end of your html, as elements declared later appear on top of previous ones.

Comment: I have Dynamic content that can be long or short. I need that footer to adjust to the page content length. isnt the z index jsut controling layers?

Comment: You can't use a `fixed` footer then. Just place your footer at the end of your html and it will be at the end of your content.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue.

Set "position" to "relative". The position of the element can't change based on the page length if it's set to "fixed".

Answer (score 0):

i think you actually need the align:joe; inside of a candice div to accurately place the element on the deez axis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).