# CSS:placing footer

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

[image: footer problem]

I'm having a problem that when there is a small amount of content on the page the footer goes up , and when there is a lot of content on the page , the footer is okay because it is in the bottom.

so i written this code in the footer:

```
position:absolute;bottom:0px;
```

and now when there is a small amount of content in the page , the footer is okay! but when there is a lot amount of content in the page , **the footer is in the middle of the page**

how can i solve this problem?

thank you in advance.

Comment: There must be a million duplicates of this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Footer at bottom:

1. Fixed Footer Height:
    http://jsfiddle.net/EP6Hn/1/
2. Fixed Footer Height & Vertical Alignment Middle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/KUEYm/
3. Flexible Footer Height:
    http://jsfiddle.net/QWb4H/
4. Flexible Footer Height & Vertical Alignment Middle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/QGFAV/
5. Footer at bottom + PNG background stretches to a height of content:
    http://jsfiddle.net/EXTyU/

Comment: Just ran into the same issue and was about to ask the question, before I realized that this must be a *really* common issue. Thanks for the examples. Oh, and just FYI, the first example can do without the nested `w1` div. See http://jsfiddle.net/EP6Hn/2/

Comment: Are you sure?)
Find 1 difference:
http://i.minus.com/irbzPQS9zCCwX.gif

Comment: Interesting; it worked fine for Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9 when I tested it. I'll just stick with the nested div then.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page for a number of my projects. This site has an excellent tutorial http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

The idea behind the tutorial is making sure that the page vertically fills the browser viewport. Once you have that issue solved then your footer will stick to the bottom.