# flexible-height sticky footer, or: Make block consume all available space

Tags: html, css

After skimming countless nigh-identical web tutorials for sticky footers and reading all linked questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776367/css-making-a-div-consume-all-available-space) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer), i only found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066645/cssplacing-footer/9067633#9067633), but not before i’ve already [thought of one](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsheep/ZATz8/) myself.

both work without javascript and adapt to any footer height; neither is clean.

1. mine contains superfluous markup (one per header, footer and content, and one wrapper); and undefined CSS behavior (specifying a table row to have a height of 100% makes it consume as much space in firefox, not 100% of something like e.g. the screen height, like it possibly does in IE)
2. the linked solution #3 contains enormous amounts of superfluous markup, even more than mine.

---

is there a less hackish version? i don’t care about medium-old browsers, as long as the newest stable versions of firefox and chrome support it, it’s fine.

PS: found a browser bug while experienting with [flex-boxes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=734525)