# Hide footer if website scrolls, display it if it doesn't

Tags: html, css

before I ask the question here are my two constraints:

- should work in IE 7+
- I can only change the CSS, I can not change the HTML/JS

So, I've got two div's:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

"#content" is the content.
"#footer" is a footer which only contains a background image and nothing that is really of value.

**Now, how can I hide part of the footer when the page is so long that it scrolls, but display it completely when the page doesn't scroll?**

(So far, I have tried stuff like:

```
#footer {height: 30px; margin-bottom: -20px;}
```

but that doesn't seem to work...)

Comment: You need sticky footer technique for  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer

Comment: I forgot two additional things:
 the page is centered with "margin: 0 auto;", 
#content does not always extend to the bottom of the page (so it doesn't have "height: 100%"), but #footer needs to come directly/no gaps after  #content

Answer (score 0):

here you have a solution only with HTML and CSS:

Source:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Example:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Good Luck

Comment: This is not what I want. The footer should not be fixed at the end of the screen. It should come gaplessly after #content, but when content is so long that the page scrolls, I want part of the footer to completely hide.